# Improve a regular expression on a ruby code

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following script

```
file = File.new("jobs.txt", 'r')
h = {}
jobs = []
salaries= []
while (line = file.gets)
    if ( line =~ /CODE/)
        cargos << line.gsub("\n", "")
    elsif (line =~ /SALARY/)
            salarios << line.gsub("\n", "")
    end
end
h = Hash[jobs.zip(salaries)]
h.each { |code, salary| puts "#{code} ------ #{salary}" }
```

It gets the job done but I want to make the regex ignore the /CODE/ it matches and return the rest of the line, is it possible to do this only on the regex or I have to code it myself (replacing strings or something like that).

I am mostly trying to figure how to make the code as small as possible.

Comment: `puts $~[1] if (line =~ /CODE(.*)$/)` if I correctly understoog what do you want.

Comment: http://rubular.com/ - use this to test alternative regex structures on test data.

Comment: What does your input look like? Do you want to ignore only the `CODE` or everything before it as well?

Comment: The input is something like this
`CODE - XXXXX\n
SALARY - XXXX\n
OTHER INFO - XXXX\n`
I want to ignore only the `CODE`

Comment: Please always check that the code you post works.  `"salaries"` is spelled incorrectly in one place, `cargos` is not initialized and `jobs` is not needed.  (I suspect you meant `jobs` where you wrote `cargos`). Get into the habit of cutting and pasting your  code into IRB or PRY before clicking on "Post Your Answer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't very idiomatic. This is untested but looks about right:

```
salarios = []
cargos = []
File.foreach("jobs.txt") do |line|

  if ( line =~ /CODE/)
    cargos << line[/CODE - (\S+)/, 1]
  elsif (line =~ /SALARY/)
    salarios << line[/SALARY - (\S+)/, 1]
  end

end
h = Hash[cargos.zip(salaries)]
h.each { |code, salary| puts "#{code} ------ #{salary}" }
```

`line[/CODE = (\S+)/, 1]` takes advantage of String's `[]` method, which lets us pass in a number of different types of parameters. In this case I'm using a regex pattern with a capture. `1` tells Ruby to return the first capture in the pattern:

```
'CODE - XXXXX'[/CODE - (\S+)/, 1] # => "XXXXX"
```

`\S+` means "one or more non-whitespace characters" so basically the pattern is saying "Find 'CODE - ' then capture the next string of characters until a space, tab, line-feed or carriage-return is found.

An alternate way to find and capture the values is to take advantage of Ruby's setting of "magic" variables when a pattern matches and contains captures:

```
if ( line =~ /CODE - (\S+)/)
  cargos << $1
elsif (line =~ /SALARY - (\S+)/)
  salarios << $1
end
```

Here's a bit of proof:

```
'CODE - XXXXX' =~ /CODE - (\S+)/
$1 # => "XXXXX"
```

Some people don't like using the Regexp magic variables; As long as you use them immediately, before anything else has a chance to run another regex match, you'll be OK. If another match occurs the variables can be overwritten and you'll have a bug.

Back to your code. Use `foreach` with a block to read the lines from the file, instead of opening and assigning to a variable. Ruby will automatically close the file after the block exits.

Comment: Nice explaination. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the input is something like this `CODE - XXXXX SALARY - XXXX OTHER INFO - XXXX`, to yield the codes:

```
cargos << $1 if (line =~ /CODE\D+(\d+)/)
salarios << $1 if (line =~ /SALARY\D+(\d+)/)
```

Here the regular expression is matched for `CODE` followed by al least one non-digit (`\D+`), followed by **captured** digits, which are meant to represent the code.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful about searching for `"CODE"` and `"SALARY"` separately.  If there are problems with the data, you may never know it (e.g., `"...CODE...CODE....SALARY..."` or an exception may be raised (if, for example, `zip` is executed when `jobs` and `salaries` are different sizes).

Here's how I would do it.  The method returns the desired result if the data is OK, else `nil`.

**Code**

```
def doit(lines)
  a = lines.select { |s| s =~ /CODE|SALARY/ }
  return nil unless a.size.even?
  jobs, salaries = a.each_slice(2).to_a.transpose
  return nil unless jobs.all?     { |l| l.scan(/CODE|SALARY/) == ["CODE"]   }
  return nil unless salaries.all? { |l| l.scan(/CODE|SALARY/) == ["SALARY"] }
  jobs.zip salaries
end
```

**Examples**

```
text =<<-_
CODE and
SALARY are good, but
CODE without
any
SALARY is not
so good
_

doit(text.split("\n"))
  #=> [["CODE and", "SALARY are good, but"], ["CODE without", "SALARY is not"]]

text =<<-_
CODE and
SALARY are good, but
SALARY without
CODE is even
better
_

doit(text.split("\n"))
  #=> nil

text =<<-_
CODE and
SALARY are good, but
CODE is the main thing
_

doit(text.split("\n"))
  #=> nil
```

**Explanation**

- `lines.select { |s| s =~ /CODE|SALARY/ }` pulls out all the lines that contain the word `"CODE"` or `"SELECT"`.
- `each_slice(2).to_a` pairs the selected lines and then converts the enumerator to an array with two columns
- `transpose` extracts the columns of the array.  The first column should be be the `"CODE"` lines; the second column, the `"SALARY"` lines.
- `jobs.all? { |l| l.scan(/CODE|SALARY/) == ["CODE"] }` ensures that each `"CODE"` line contains `"CODE"` exactly once and does not contain `"SALARY"`.  The next line of code does the opposite for the `"SALARY"` lines.
- the last line returns the desired result.